# Light disappears when shadows is turned on

Tags: shadows

I am using Blender 2.93.4, Windows 10, Surface Go 2 and I am very new to it.

I have a scene with point light with initially shadows unchecked. I switched `Viewport shading` to `Display render preview`; In `Viewport shading` `Scene lights` is checked; render engine is set to `Eevee`.

Light is displaying, all is good:
[image]

Now in light settings I check `Shadows` and the light disappears, and no shadows (obviously, there is not light):
[image]

None of renders engine displays shadows. Shadows are not displayed from\on just simple cubes with no material, and geometry with material (building in screenshot).

What should I do to display shadows?

[image]

Comment: This is rather unusual, but I can’t tell any unusual settings in your screenshot that would make this happen. Can you test: does the same file work correctly on a different computer?

Comment: @TheLabCat Unfortunately no. Maybe I can send You my `blend` file?

Comment: Go ahead and blend-exchange.com it and I’ll see if I can get a round tuit

Comment: @TheLabCat done

Comment: I have tested on EEVEE, and got shadows on a pink building (yeah, missing textures. No biggie). I am now testing on Cycles. If it shows up there, delete the question, and report as a bug on developer.blender.org and I hope you get it fixed. 

Comment: Confirmed, regular shadows are showing up in cycles.

Comment: Wait a minute, that’s really weird. I switched over to the viewport just to make sure it was still working, and it was. But as soon as I orbited the viewport away from the camera view I had it in, the scene turned “waiting for render” gray, although the little debug in the corner still showed the sample count going up, and it finishing. This does not happen with EEVEE.

Comment: That bug doesn’t happen in the default file, only to yours. That’s really weird, so be sure to include that file in the bug report.

Comment: @TheLabCat thank You for help, but Emir solution solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "Render region" On. Turn it off by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> (for the sidebar) then click on view and turn off Render region.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, it solved the problem, You rock

Comment: I am really sorry for disturbing, but it again does not work. After it started work I continued modeling, and, probably pressed wrong shortcuts. Now there is no light if shadows turned on even with `render region` unchecked...

Comment: It does not work with `Workbench` also, but it works, though with very low-resolution almost like pixel art, in `Cycles`

Comment: I uploaded current scene, maybe You can find issue there https://blend-exchange.com/b/4m6SrWm9

Comment: Workbench doesn't support regular light objects, it's the regular engine used for the 3D viewport

Comment: Eevvee doesn't displays lights with shadows though

Comment: i just open your file and it's working correctly for me on EEVEE and Cycles, you probably have a graphics card issue. [Renders](https://imgur.com/a/LyYO2ek)

Comment: Possibly, but why it worked after Your initial remark? If we suppose, that it is too much difficult scene for my graphic card, it probably not the reason, because I have not complicated the scene so much after shadows started to work. I hope that I just pressed something. For example, trying to enter FPS mode by pressing `SHIFT` + `  ~ ``, I often press `SHIFT` + `TAB` instead, and as I noticed this is another command

Comment: I have really been doubting that it will work, but I just restarted blender, and shadows now works again. Can't answer for sure - is it problem with my pc or with Blender

Comment: It could be your scene file. Try to open your objects in a new scene